# How to solve openCV function,symbol,type not resolved error?

Tags: opencv

I am using **Windows 7 64-bit edition** with **openCV 2.4.6 and mingw** installed on **Eclipse bundle**. I have properly added the libraries and included the openCV header files with all of them shown in project explorer window.

However, even though there is no error for header files, there are errors for every **function, symbol, type, method** which says **not resolved**. However, the same code runs perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2010.